# How to display other app in surface view?

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-mediaprojection, android-virtualdisplay, android-displaymanager

I would like to mirror e.g. Waze in my app SurfaceView:

```
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.waze"); //"com.waze"

    Bundle opts = ActivityOptions
            .makeBasic()
            .setLaunchDisplayId(virtualDisplay.getDisplay().getDisplayId())
            .toBundle();

    startActivity(intent, opts);
```

I'm getting a permission denied error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent
```

Would I have a workaround for it? Would it be possible?